# How to isolate the contents of an xml tag after a soap request

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap

I just created a soap request using curl and I'm trying to isolate the content of an xml tag in order to use it in another soap request.

Here is my code :

```
$xml_data = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns1="qsfd" xmlns:ns2="qsdf" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

```
  <ns2:GetStock>

     <ns2:request>

        <ns1:StockRequests>

           <ns1:StockRequest>

              <ns1:CustomerNo>qsf</ns1:CustomerNo>

              <ns1:Division>qsdf</ns1:Division>

              <ns1:Item>qsdf</ns1:Item>

           </ns1:StockRequest>

        </ns1:StockRequests>

     </ns2:request>

  </ns2:GetStock>
```

```
$URL = "qsdf";
$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml', 'SOAPAction:qsdf'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo htmlentities($output);
die();
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. Please clarify which content you want to get. If you want to parse XML you can user SimpleXML and (if the structure is more complex) XPath to get your desired content.

Comment: In the xml answer I get, there is a tag <a:stock> that I want to use.

Comment: I see please post the answer from the XML too.